# Write in an HTML file with data of a form of another HTML file whit JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have got two files: `upload.html` and `data.html`

`upload.html` has this form:

```
<form class="subir_py" type="POST">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="titlepage">
        <h2>Datos</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <input
            class="contactus"
            placeholder="Name"
            type="text"
            id="name"
            required
        />
        </div>                 
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea
            class="textarea"
            placeholder="Description"
            type="text"
            name="Message"
            id="message"
        ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input
            class="imagearea"
            type="hidden"
            name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
            value="4194304"
        />
        <input type="file" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <button
            id="btnUpload"
            class="btnUpload"
            type="button"
            onclick="getData()"
        >
            Subir
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see I've got some data to collect there and an image.
Now, I want to write the data collected in this form in the div with id "proyects" in data.html

So, I created `app.js`:

```
function getData() { 
  const nombreProyecto = document.getElementById("name").value;
  const nombreOrganizacion = document.getElementById("message").value;
}

function writeData() {
  var newDivName = document.createElement("div");
  newDivName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(proyectName));
  document.getElementById("proyects").appendChild(proyectName);
}
```

The problem is that as they are different html files, it does not find the div called "proyects" in the `data.html` file.
I've tried to use webpack, but as I already have all the html and css done it's difficult to bundle everything now. Does anyone know another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Since it's a different html file, it's a different page, right? The browser loads in-between? Every time the page loads, you have a clean slate. If you need to store that data over page loads, you need to preserve this server-side.

Comment: Or, at the very least, save the data to `localStorage` so the new page can pick it up.

Comment: Okay I'll try. thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you can get the page content easily through AJAX (use `fetch()` in modern browsers).